# To fetch last 10 record ,adding 'LIMIT' to MySQL queries make it faster?

Tags: mysql

Can someone explain if i want to  fetch last 10 records ,adding 'LIMIT' to MySQL queries make it faster? 
like

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `table`
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

is there any other way to fetch last 10 record or is it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `limit` is it must order **all** the rows in the table *before* returning only the last 50, so it's always going to be slow and will get slower as the table grows (not scaleable).

The fastest way to get the last 50 is:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  `table`
WHERE id > (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table`) - 50
```

This will use the index on `id` to get the max id and again to get the top 50.

---

You should also try this slightly more complicated but potentially better optimisable:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  `table`
WHERE id BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table`) - 49
    AND (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table`)
```

Compare actual run times andcuse the fastest.

Comment: bt internally it uses two query 1st 1 inner query after that outer so is it faster than limit?

Comment: @mjsoft it should be faster yes, but why not try it and report back the timings of your query and each of my two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Adding Limit would make it faster. Thats correct. In this case the last 10 records that were inserted to the database will be selected

Comment: ya but why..? means for fetching last 10 records it will travel through all rows then it must take more time.. means using ORDER BY id DESC it will count all rows and then ti will call limit

Answer (score 0):

You can derived table instead of the limit using `IN` or `subquery` which can be followed by a dynamic `rownum` variable. But this may be very complex and slow alternative.
So, I suggest you to use the **same query** for fetching the last row from your table instead of any other alternative. Becuase of if you want to use a subquery then be you have to track the max id data and maybe some of the data is deleted or removed then it's can't return a proper number of records.
And also you can use `col name` instead of `*` for more optimization.